# Mp4 file is not playing when finished download with c socket

Tags: c, sockets, video, mp4

I am trying to download mp4 video using C socket. File downloaded successfully but when i am try to play it is not working. File is same as original file size. But their checksum is differents. But this code is working fine for pdf file.
I am grateful and appreciate for your afford.

```
int main() {

    int socket_desc;
    char *message;
    char server_reply[100000];
    char *file_path = "file.mp4";
    ssize_t total_len = 0;
    char *ip = NULL;

    FILE *file = NULL;
    struct sockaddr_in server;

    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1) {
        printf("dCould not create socket");
    }

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("195.154.200.24");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(80);

    if (connect(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
        printf("connect error");
        return 1;
    }

    message = "GET /upload_file/367/382/Indian%20Pop%20Hit%20Video%20Songs/Indian%20Pop%20Video%20Songs%202016%20-%20MP4/Jammin%20-%20Yaara%20-%20A%20R%20Rahman%20-%20Video%20MP4.mp4 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: dl.pagal.link\r\n\r\n";

    if (send(socket_desc, message, strlen(message), 0) < 0) {
        printf("Send failed");
        return 1;
    }

    remove( file_path );
    file = fopen( file_path , "ab");

    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("File %s could not opened", file_path);
        return 1;
    }

    while (1) {
        ssize_t received_len = recv(socket_desc, server_reply, sizeof(server_reply), 0);

        if (received_len < 0) {
           printf("Received failed\n");
            return -1;
        }
        if (received_len == 0) {
            break;
        }

        fwrite(server_reply, (size_t) received_len, 1, file);
    }

    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code you show shouldn't even *compile!* (Not even when put into [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) There are also at least one source of possible *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Can you use a diff tool?
Download the file manually and then using your code.
Diff your file to see the difference and to find out whether your code is failing in start, in between or at end.

Comment: I downloaded that mp4 using downloader and it is playing.

Comment: You're missing `\r\n\r\n` terminator after the headers.

Comment: also, why not just use `wb`.

Comment: @Antti change to wb from ab and also added \r\n\r\n but not working.

Comment: If you are using Linux, please use binary diff, please look at this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/125376/how-do-i-compare-binary-files-in-linux) on how to compare binary files in Linux.
If you are using windows use any good diff tool to compare the files e.g. _Beyond Compare_

Comment: @Gaurav Pathank  Thanks issue resolved.

Comment: Please let us know what was the issue and what you did to solve the issue. So that if anyone visits this question he/she should get to know the answer,

Comment: I was trying to adding bytes when first time content info coming so just need to add only file bytes not content related bytes will be resolve the problem. thanks for good suggestion.